# Difficulty installing gatsby-plugin-sass because of xcode

Tags: npm, sass, gatsby

I'm trying to install `gatsby-plugin-sass` and I'm getting the following error:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

I can't find anything that tells me how to get past this error and I absolutely do not want to download the memory hog known as Xcode.

`xcode-select` is already installed, verified when I run `xcode-select -install`.  And I vaguely remember installing it a long time ago to get Sass to work (and Sass still works on my system.)

Is there a way to satisfy this error that doesn't involve installing XCode?  I really don't want to waste the gigabytes on it.

It appears to actually be an issue with node-gyp yet none of the fixes on their issues page seem to work for me.

Comment: are you also installing `sass` at the same time, or this error happens when you're only installing `gatsby-plugin-sass`?

Comment: I already have Sass installed, had it installed globally ages ago.  I wasn't attempting to install a local version of Sass, other than `gatsby-plugin-sass`.  It also wouldn't let me install `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` for the same error.